# PHP Shell_exec Live Output in a box

Tags: php, html, bash, shell

I am trying to run `shell.sh $folderPath $khz $group2` and display the live output in a box on a page.

However, when I click submit, I get no output.

How do I get real time output from my php script?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>AppTek</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/splitter.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="splitter.php">
        <label for="folderPath">Folder Path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="folderPath" name="folderPath">
    <br></br>
        <fieldset id="khz">
            <p>Please Choose Khz: </p>
          <input type="radio" value="8khz" name="khz"> 8khz <br>
          <input type="radio" value="16khz" name="khz"> 16khz <br>
        </fieldset>
    <br></br>
        <fieldset id="audio-type">
            <p>Please Choose Type: </p>
          <input type="radio" value="C12" name="group2"> Channel 1 & 2 <br>
          <input type="radio" value="LR" name="group2"> Left to Right <br>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="spaceh10"></div>
        <input class = "submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">

    <div class="spaceh10"></div>
    <div style="width:500px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000;">
    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['folderPath']) && !empty($_GET['folderPath']) && is_dir($_GET['folderPath']) && 
        isset($_GET['khz']) && isset($_GET['group2'])) {

        $folderPath = $_GET['folderPath'];
        $khz = $_GET['khz'];
        $group2 = $_GET['group2'];

        $run = shell_exec("shell.sh $folderPath $khz $group2");
        while (@ ob_end_flush()); 

        $proc = popen($run, 'r');
        echo '<pre>';
        while (!feof($proc))
        {
            echo fread($proc, 4096);
            @ flush();
        }
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and shell.sh would be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "path: $1 arg1: $2 arg2: $3"
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
    $run = shell_exec("shell.sh {$folderPath} {$khz} {$group2}");
```

Doesn't look like you're passing those variable properly.  If that doesn't work, maybe do the string separately.

```
    $command = 'shell.sh {$folderPath} {$khz} {$group2}';
    $run = shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This doesn't work either. I am going to update my post to show you an example .sh file

Comment: Also the problem is that even when I do simple echo, it doesn't display anything

Comment: Can you run it from the command line?  I would start there.  Make sure the shell.sh file actually works from the command line and accepts the arguments before you try it from PHP.

Comment: It just doesn't display anything on the webpage